# How to calculate total time duration from individual durations

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am unable to calculate total time duration from individual durations

I have already tried below formats

> 1.) h:mm
>
> 2.) [h]:mm
>
> 3.) [h]:mm;@

Below are  my excel time duration values

```
0:09
5:54
1:55
0:16
0:05
0:04
0:52
0:45
6:29
3:08
2:40
0:00
0:01
1:27
0:02
0:09
0:06
0:01
2:36
0:00
5:23
3:15
3:01
2:02
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You want to sum your range but that isn't working? Using `SUM()` on your sample data gives 16:20. What is your expected result.

Comment: The Problem you must be facing is That `hh` only counts till 23 and becomes 0 next. and the counter is added to the `dd`. Use the format in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` on your range. While that gives `16:20` as output, format that cell with custom format `[hh]:mm`.

So using `=SUM(A1:A24)` with custom format `[hh]:mm` on `B1` returns `40:20`

[image]

If your values are actually textvalues looking like timevalues this will return `00:00` as per your comment.

To overcome this issue, use formula: `=SUM(TIMEVALUE(A1:A24))` and confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and keep the same format as mentioned above, `[hh]:mm`.

Comment: Thank for answering my question.I tried your instruction.Modified format and applied sum function.but not working it is showing 00:00

Comment: Are your values actual time values? Or is it text written to look like a time value? Cause that would add up to `00:00` @chandrarv, please check edited answer

Comment: Thanks for help.Your solution is working in blank doc.I have system generated doc. so may be that has a problem.

Comment: @chandrarv, is it possible to post the system generated doc?

Comment: How can i share

Comment: Google Drive Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By2udOgSvy2paDd1bEJsUTdJcHhsRXJYVFMyaHhMNkFZQ3lV/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @chandrarv, So it is exactly what I told you, it's textvalues looking like timevalues. On your given sheet this works: `=SUM(TIMEVALUE(Table1[Actual Duration]))` enter through Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Data is Like for the second value `5:54` as `5 Hours 54 Minutes`...

The Total is Coming out to be `40 Hours 20 minutes`. For this you need to apply the format as :  `dd:hh:mm` Which will give you complete day for 24 hours and 16 hours for hh and 20 mm for minutes. That would be your 40 Hours 20 Minues in total.

You can do as per the screenshot also to get the Hours & Minutes. Then perform the conversion to get the result.

[image]

Comment: Thank for answering my question.I tried your instruction.Modified format and applied sum function.but not working it is showing 00:00:00

Comment: @chandrarv ... Check the screenshot. You can do this also. By doing this you will get to know if there is issue in any value

Comment: Thanks for help.Your solution is working in blank doc.I have system generated doc. so may be that has a problem.

Comment: What is the Format of the Doc & if possible can you share ?

Comment: How can i share

Comment: Upload it on your Dropbox or OneDrive or Google Drive and share the link.

Comment: Google Drive Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By2udOgSvy2paDd1bEJsUTdJcHhsRXJYVFMyaHhMNkFZQ3lV/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gl4Uu3JR91J0GPe1JxwJosYtgrWYl6Ze)  .. See the formula